# How to embed 32 or 64 bit ActiveX control on same page depending on browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an ActiveX control that has both 32 and 64 bit versions for 32 and 64 bit browsers.  At run time, I can detect the browser version and redirect to a copied deployment of the same pages, but referencing the 64-bit code base.    Is there any way to have a single set of pages but change the referenced code base file (.cab file) at run time based on browser?  This is in Visual Studio ASP.NET, with the control embedded in a form at design time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is client side, you should be able to use that code in any IE supporting ActiveX:

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
var cab_to_download = "http://server/activex." +
window.navigator.cpuClass + ".cab";
--></script>
```

you would have to name your CABs 'activex.x86.cab' and 'activex.x64.cab' in the sample, and use that for your `codebase=""` attribute with some `document.write()` call in client side.